docker ls showing processes but webserver not connecting
I'm at the very last part of an assignment and for the life of me I can't get this to work.
I need to host a website that is deployed by a gitlab cicd pipeline, needs to run tests, build and deploy all automically.
I'm hosting with digitalOcean and all my jobs succeed, in docker ps it shows the containers but when I go to the webaddress it doesn't want to connect
I'll give everything, so there will be some unnecessary information, but I'm just lost right now, I'll be forever thankful if you can help me
(images are public on docker hub listed in the yml file)
Pastebin of build output: https://pastebin.com/fdGbH0e4
Pastebin of deploy output: https://pastebin.com/S2jAjTUY
.gitlab-ci.yml
variables:
  IMAGE_NAME_BACKEND: sjorsnl77/pipeline_ipsenh-backend
  IMAGE_NAME_FRONTEND: sjorsnl77/pipeline_ipsenh-frontend
  IMAGE_TAG: ipsenh-app-1.0

stages:
  - verify
  - build
  - tests
  - deploy

services:
  - docker:dind

verify_backend:
  stage: verify
  image: maven:3.9.6-amazoncorretto-17
  script:
    - cd PintAndPillageJavaBackend
    - mvn checkstyle:checkstyle
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}-maven
    paths:
      - .m2/repository/
    policy: pull-push
  artifacts:
    when: always
    expire_in: 1 day
    paths:
      - "PintAndPillageJavaBackend/target/checkstyle-result.xml"

verify_frontend:
  stage: verify
  image: node:latest
  script:
    - cd PintAndPillageFrontend
    - npm ci
    - ./node_modules/.bin/eslint . --output-file eslint-report.txt --quiet || true
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}-npm
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - "PintAndPillageFrontend/eslint-report.txt"
    expire_in: 1 day


build:
  stage: build
  image: docker
  services:
    - docker:dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
  before_script:
    - docker login -u "$DOCKER_USER" -p "$DOCKER_PASS"
  script:
    - docker build -t $IMAGE_NAME_BACKEND:$IMAGE_TAG PintAndPillageJavaBackend
    - docker build -t $IMAGE_NAME_FRONTEND:$IMAGE_TAG PintAndPillageFrontend
    - docker push $IMAGE_NAME_BACKEND:$IMAGE_TAG
    - docker push $IMAGE_NAME_FRONTEND:$IMAGE_TAG
  cache:
    paths:
      - .m2/repository/
      - node_modules/

test_backend:
  stage: tests
  image: docker
  script:
    - docker login -u "$DOCKER_USER" -p "$DOCKER_PASS"
    - docker-compose up --build -d db backend
    - docker-compose exec backend ./mvnw test
    - docker-compose exec backend sh -c "cp -r target/surefire-reports/. /test-output/backend/"
    - docker-compose down
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - test-output/backend/
    expire_in: 1 day

test_frontend:
  stage: tests
  image: docker
  script:
    - docker login -u "$DOCKER_USER" -p "$DOCKER_PASS"
    - docker-compose up --build -d frontend
    - docker-compose exec frontend npm run test:unit
    - docker-compose exec frontend sh -c "cp -r ./test-output/frontend/. /test-output/frontend/"
    - docker-compose down
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - test-output/frontend/
    expire_in: 1 day

deploy_app:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - chmod 400 $SSH_KEY
  script:
    - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $SSH_KEY root@$IP_SERVER "
        docker login -u $DOCKER_USER -p $DOCKER_PASS;
        if [ -n \"\$(docker ps -aq)\" ]; then 
          docker ps -aq | xargs docker stop | xargs docker rm; 
        fi;
        docker run -d -p 8080:8080 $IMAGE_NAME_BACKEND:$IMAGE_TAG;
        docker run -d -p 3000:3000 $IMAGE_NAME_FRONTEND:$IMAGE_TAG;
      "


docker-compose.yml
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: PintAndPillage
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  backend:
    build:
      context: ./PintAndPillageJavaBackend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: dev
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: ${DATASOURCE_URL}
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: ${DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: ${DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
      SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DIALECT: ${HIBERNATE_DIALECT}
      SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO: ${HIBERNATE_DDL}
      SERVER_ERROR_INCLUDE_MESSAGE: always
      JWT_SECRET: ${JWT_SECRET}
    volumes:
      - ./test-output/backend:/test-output/backend


  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./PintAndPillageFrontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./test-output/frontend:/test-output/frontend

volumes:
  postgres-data:


Dockerfile frontend
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN npm install
CMD ["npm", "run", "serve"]

Dockerfile backend
FROM openjdk:17
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN chmod +x mvnw
RUN ./mvnw install
CMD ["./mvnw", "spring-boot:run"]



Even the terminal shows it (weird that the backend is now not showing, but even without the backend it should run the frontend, but you just can't log in)
188.166.4.5:3000, 188.166.4.5:8080, 188.166.4.5. All don't work with connecting
